# Why is the margin space of my image link clickable?

Tags: html, css

I am building a website for a friend, and part of his specification is that images should include links to view the image in a higher resolution. I enclosed the home image in an anchortag within a div, but I can't figure out why my image's margin space is clickable.

I'm assuming that it has to do with the image being inside of a div?

Here is my jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9kSL3/5/

Here are the areas of interest:

```
<div id="home">
<a href="./images/home3.jpg"><img src='http://s17.postimg.org/4glpnzdan/home3.jpg' border='0' alt="home3" /></a>
</div>



#home img{
    width: 60%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    /*border-radius: 15px;
    border: 1px;*/
}
```

What's strange to me is that in this answer: [Remove space around clickable image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843744/remove-space-around-clickable-image) the answer is to use margin instead of padding

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's because you have an `img` using `display: block` inside an `a` tag, which is inline.

Move the `width: 60%` and `margin: 0 auto;` to the `a` tag with `display: block` and add `width: 100%` to `img`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/9kSL3/6/

Comment: Same issue for me. And I dont know the width of the image. So this solution is not working. Any help?

Comment: post a new question

Answer (score 3):

It's because you've set the image to display as a block element (I assume you did this for centering). If you remove the `display: block` line and add a section for the #home div as so:
`#home {
    text-align: center;
}`

It should work for you and the margins will not be "clickable"

Comment: I liked this answer as well, I just found the first more informative as to why display: block did what it did

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by setting the **parent** div of the `<a>` element to `text-align: center` and the `<img>` to `display: inline`.

```
.parent-div-of-your-a-tag {
    text-align: center;

}

.your-img-class-name {
    width: 100%;     // might not be necessary, I needed them for responsive design
    height: auto;    // see above
    display: inline; // necessary 
}
```